# Proof of the linearity of complex integrals for paths of bounded variation?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am familiar with the proof of the linearity of complex integrals for piece-wise smooth paths. Nonetheless, complex integrals can be defined for more general paths $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$ where $\gamma$ is of bounded variation (and not necessarily (piecewise)smooth). Let $f$ and $f$ be continuous functions from $[a,b]$ to the complex plane. which is the proof of
$$
\int_a^b\alpha{}f(z)\,dz=\alpha{}\int_a^bf(z)\,dz\qquad\int_a^b\bigg(f(z)+g(z)\bigg)\,dz=\int_a^bf(z)\,dz+\int_a^bg(z)\,dz
$$
 in this more general setting?

Comment: I don't understand: why would the proof be any different at all?

Comment: how do you define $\int_\gamma f(z)dz$ when $\gamma$ is not (piecewise) $C^1$ ? @Joanpemo

Comment: @user1952009 I've a rather good idea how, but it is up to the asker to tell us.In my opinion the (Riemann) sums used for one can also be used for the other, though convergence will be, I guess, tougher or more restricted, if you prefer. Anyway, after that is done I can't see how for a function and a path for which the sums converge, the basic linear properties of the integral (line or whatever) won't be true and, in fact, the proofs must be identical or almost. A good example of things close to this one is the Riemann-Stieltjes integral, say.

Comment: @Joanpemo : yes of course I agree, the situation is the same in every type of integrals/summation, and is a consequence of the usual linearity of limits : $\lim_{a \to b} F(a) + G(a) = \lim_{a \to b} F(a) +\lim_{a \to b} G(a)$ whenever the 3 limits exist. here I'd say $F(a) = \int_{\gamma_a} f(z) dz, G(a) = \int_{\gamma_a} g(z) dz$ where $\gamma_a$ is a nice curve converging in some way to $\gamma$ (hence we also require  $f,g$ to be continuous in the neighborhood of $\gamma$)

Answer (score 1):

To whom it may concern. Let us name
$$
\int_a^bf(z)\,dz\equiv{}I_1\qquad\int_a^b\alpha{}f(z)\,dz\equiv{}I_2
$$
Let's pick any $\epsilon_1>0$. By definition there is a $\delta_1$ such that for any partition $P={a=t_0<t_1<\ldots<t_m=b}$ satistying $||P||<\delta_1$ (where $t_{k-1}\leq\tau_k\leq{}t_k$)
$$
\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^mf(\tau_k)\big[\gamma(t_k)-\gamma(t_{k-1})\big]-I_1\bigg|<\epsilon_1
$$
by definition also for an $\epsilon_2<0$ there is a $\delta_2<0$ such that for a partition satisfying $||P||<\delta_2$
$$
\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^m\alpha{}f(\tau_k)\big[\gamma(t_k)-\gamma(t_{k-1})\big]-I_2\bigg|<\epsilon_2
$$
Let's make a guess and check if the definition is satisfyed by $I_2=\alpha{}I_1$.
$$
\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^m\alpha{}f(\tau_k)\big[\gamma(t_k)-\gamma(t_{k-1})\big]-\alpha{}I_1\bigg|=\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^mf(\tau_k)\big[\gamma(t_k)-\gamma(t_{k-1})\big]-I_1\bigg|\big|\alpha\big|<\big|\alpha\big|\epsilon_1
$$
where to write the last inequality we assumed that $||P||<\delta_1$. Therefore we see that for every $\epsilon_2=|\alpha|\epsilon_1$ there is a $\delta_2=\delta_1$ such that the definition is satisfied for $\alpha{}I_1$ being the value of the integral.

Now the sum. same as before by definition 
$$
\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^mf(\tau_k)\big[\gamma(t_k)-\gamma(t_{k-1})\big]-I_1\bigg|<\epsilon_1
$$
$$
\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^mg(\tau_k)\big[\gamma(t_k)-\gamma(t_{k-1})\big]-I_2\bigg|<\epsilon_2
$$
Notice that the epsilons an deltas have nothing to do with the ones  from the first part. Let's now consider
$$
\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^mf(\tau_k)\big[\gamma(t_k)-\gamma(t_{k-1})\big]+g(\tau_k)\big[\gamma(t_k)-\gamma(t_{k-1})\big]-I_1-I_2\bigg|\leq{}\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^mf(\tau_k)\big[\gamma(t_k)-\gamma(t_{k-1})\big]-I_1\bigg|+\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^mg(\tau_k)\big[\gamma(t_k)-\gamma(t_{k-1})\big]-I_2\bigg|<\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2
$$
wehre i have considered $||P||<inf(\delta_1,\delta_2)$. Therefore for $\epsilon=\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2$ and $\delta=inf(\delta_1,\delta_2)$ the definition is satisfied. Thus, the complec integral is linear.